# Synchronize from QField (QFieldSync) Not Working - Getting Handle Bad Layers pop-up

Tags: qgis, qfield

I am using QField with QGIS to edit data in the field. I used QFieldSync to package my QGIS project and was able to open it on my Android device and edit/add features just fine. I then copy the folder from my Android device to my desktop; go to my QGIS project; and select the folder through QFieldSync's 'Synchronize from QField'. The result is the 'Handle Bad Layers' pop-up in QGIS and I don't know how to proceed.

[image]

Can anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong? Here is some information:

Data: .shp files

QFieldSync Project Configuration: I've set the Action for all three layers to offline editing since I need to be able to make changes to the .shp files in the office while others are making updates in the field.

Python version: 3.6.0

QGIS version: 3.0.3-Girona

QField version: QField for QGIS - RELEASE CANDIDATE 3

Comment: Is the project set to use relative or absolute filepaths?

Comment: The project is set to use the relative filepaths:  Project ‣ Project Properties ‣ General ‣ Save paths is set to “Relative”

Answer (score 2):

Here is what ended up working for me:
I uninstalled QGIS and installed the most recent version: 3.4.4. QFieldSync worked fine after that. I was able to import new data back from my Anrdoid device and view the new data in the QGIS project.

For some reason QFieldSync was creating a data.sqlite file when I was using QGIS3.0 but with QGIS3.4 it creates a data.gpkg file instead.

Answer (score 2):

After gps readings you can copy and paste your folder Qfield in your PC and then open Qgis desktop without project and then "synchronize from Qfield" you load your Qfield's project

I solved my problem with this method

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I've copy and paste your project in you PC instead of open from your phone/tablette....